# Understanding data partition in dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, root, disk, boot-partition

I am new to linux, and I just installed ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop (dual boot with windows). I am most likely not going to use Windows anymore, but it's kind of nice to have it there, just in case. However I need to **make more space for my root folder**. Here is my disk partition:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     370687    368640  180M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    370688     632831    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    632832  102115327 101482496 48,4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 965085184  967112703   2027520  990M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 967112704  997443583  30330880 14,5G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6 997445632 1000214527   2768896  1,3G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p7 102115328  133365759  31250432 14,9G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p8 133365760  172427263  39061504 18,6G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p9 172427264  965085183 792657920  378G Linux filesystem
```

1/ Why do I have **3 Windows recovery environment**? Did I mess up something? Can I safely delete the 2 small ones and still be able to recover Windows?

2/ What is the **Microsoft basic data**? Is it my /home equivalent in Windows? Can I safely shrink it to a very small size (it is currently empty), and expand it if I ever want to use Windows?

PS: Not sure if that matters but my laptop is a Dell xps 15

Comment: All of your questions are about Windows partitions, and here is probably not the best place to ask, as it has nothing to do with Ubuntu? There is also no way for us to know how many partitions should Windows have, or how safe it is to delete them. Given the layout, I'd shrink /dev/nvme0n1p9.

Comment: 1) You can read more about it [here](https://windowsclassroom.com/windows-10-recovery-partition/) and 2) Not exactly .  Microsoft basic data partition in this case is your C:\ Drive and Yes you can shrink it. "EFI system" partition is for installation of the bootloader (both linux and windows ) and some configuration files.

Comment: Best to shrink NTFS partitions with Windows tools. But Windows only works well with 30% free, at 10% free you just about cannot run a defrag. You have Dell recovery, Windows recovery and Windows added a new recovery just after c: drive for another recovery of some sort. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations But then vendors also add recovery partitions. When I did my full backup of my Dell, it asked if I wanted to remove my Dell recovery partition, I kept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1> Not sure why, however it has nothing to do with your ubuntu installation. There were probably already present, without you being aware of it. Windows often has multiple recovery partitions installed by default.

2> That looks like your windows data partition indeed. You can shrink it down. However there is no garantee it works out succesfully. I have shrunk NTFS partitions a dozen times without a problem, but you never know for sure. Make always a good backup! You could use a tool like gparted to manage your partitions easily (including windows partitions).
When you change the order of partitions you could accidentally screw up your grub boot loader (changes are really low nowadays). In such a case it might good to note the drives down like you did above but after your repartitioning. If grub fails after a (re)boot, start a recovery session, and adapt your /etc/fstab so it matches your partitions again, and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: +1 and welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you also comment on shrinking partition `nvme0n1p91` ?